# Need help on tkinter about object detection program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, object-detection

I am trying to make a tkinter window where the user presses a button and the user inputs an img for the program to scan it.What I want is for the image to appear on the tkinter window and also for the program to not end and instead continue so the user inputs another image.My output is this one:

https://prnt.sc/w837e2

https://prnt.sc/w838c2

https://prnt.sc/w83c69

The tk window is destroyed and all that is showing is the output.Also when the filedialog opens and the user doesnt input an image the tkwindow closes as well.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


def search_image():                                                              
    global image1
    image1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    root.destroy()
    return image1

root = tk.Tk()                                                                   
root.geometry('1200x900-100-100')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('YOLO')
w = tk.Label(root, text = "IMAGE-DETECTION-YOLO", font = "Arial 36", bg ='lightgray', width = 900)
w.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text = "CHOOSE", font = "Arial 36", command = search_image)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()


#######after that is code for the detection model############################


# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", default=image1,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt",
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel",
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the list of class labels MobileNet SSD was trained to
# detect, then generate a set of bounding box colors for each class
CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
    "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
    "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
    "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3))

# load our serialized model from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")
model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

# load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
# by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
# (note: normalization is done via the authors of the MobileNet SSD
# implementation)
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

# pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
# predictions
print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
model.setInput(blob)
detections = model.forward()

# loop over the detections
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
    # prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
        # then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
        # the object
        idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        # display the prediction
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)
        print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            COLORS[idx], 2)
        y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
        cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.imwrite('image_detected.jpg',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the detection inside a function and call this function after selecting an image file.  Also use `Pillow` module to convert the result image and show the result image using `Label`.

```py
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def detect_objects(image1):
    # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", default=image1,
        help="path to input image")
    ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt",
        help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
    ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel",
        help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
    ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2,
        help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    # initialize the list of class labels MobileNet SSD was trained to
    # detect, then generate a set of bounding box colors for each class
    CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
        "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
        "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
        "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]
    COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3))

    # load our serialized model from disk
    print("[INFO] loading model...")
    model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

    # load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
    # by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
    # (note: normalization is done via the authors of the MobileNet SSD
    # implementation)
    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
    # predictions
    print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
    model.setInput(blob)
    detections = model.forward()

    # loop over the detections
    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
        # prediction
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            # extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
            # then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            # display the prediction
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)
            print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
            cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
                COLORS[idx], 2)
            y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
            cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)

    # show the output image
    image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    result.config(image=tkimage)
    result.iamge = tkimage

def search_image():                                                              
    image1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if image1:
        detect_objects(image1)

root = tk.Tk()                                                                   
root.geometry('1200x900-100-100')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('YOLO')
w = tk.Label(root, text = "IMAGE-DETECTION-YOLO", font = "Arial 36", bg ='lightgray', width = 900)
w.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text = "CHOOSE", font = "Arial 36", command = search_image)
button.pack()
# label to show the result
result = tk.Label(root)
result.pack()
root.mainloop()
```